# Show value of default variant

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to display the value/price of the default variant for a product.

This is what I currently have:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  From {{ variant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This displays the price of every variant that a product has. How can I just display the default variant price? Or better still, the product variant with the lowest price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the default variant using `{{ product.defaultVariant }}`.

Because `product.variants` isn't an ElementCriteriaModel you can't sort it like one. You'd have to retrieve the products variants as an ElementCriteriaModel first like so:

```
{% set lowestPriceVariant = craft.commerce.variants({
  productId: product.id,
  order: 'variants.price'
}).first() %}

{{ lowestPriceVariant.title }}
```